# how to lock iwlwifi firmware version used

Tags: linux, fedora, firmware

today i logged on my Fedora 34 and my iwlwifi firmware version is returned to the newest after boot. I forgot yesterday, but i think i was doing dnf update and it's affecting the firmware version that i was remove before. So i did run this command to change the firmware version. But i want to make sure in the future the version is locked to 22, and not changing back to 27&29. Here's some information i can provide, feel free to ask more information (i'm a beginner)

```
sudo rm /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode.xz
sudo rm /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode.xz
reboot
```

```
sudo uname -r
5.14.11-200.fc34.x86_64
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 59
       serial: 10:02:b5:68:be:56
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.14.11-200.fc34.x86_64 firmware=22.391740.0 7265D-22.ucode ip=192.168.43.192 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:150 memory:dc400000-dc401fff
```

```
modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/5.14.11-200.fc34.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko.xz
license:        GPL
author:         Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-mr-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-gf4-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-mr-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-fm-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-mr-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf4-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-jf-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf4-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-64.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-64.ucode
```

```
dnf info iwl7260-firmware
Fedora 34 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                         2.7 kB/s | 4.5 kB     00:01    
Fedora 34 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                          69 kB/s | 2.6 MB     00:38    
Fedora Modular 34 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                 4.2 kB/s | 6.4 kB     00:01    
Installed Packages
Name         : iwl7260-firmware
Epoch        : 1
Version      : 25.30.13.0
Release      : 122.fc34
Architecture : noarch
Size         : 36 M
Source       : linux-firmware-20210818-122.fc34.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : updates
Summary      : Firmware for Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link 726x/8000/9000/AX200/AX201 Series Adapters
URL          : http://www.kernel.org/
License      : Redistributable, no modification permitted
Description  : This package contains the firmware required by the Intel wireless drivers
             : for Linux.  Usage of the firmware is subject to the terms and conditions
             : contained inside the provided LICENSE file. Please read it carefully.
```

best regards, Jeremy Kenn

Answer (score 0):

You can [hold the package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403181/how-to-pin-a-package-in-dnf-fedora#403204), so it won't upgrade. Either pin it or exclude from update.

But that will make all new firmwares unavailable to you. You can run a [post-transaction hook](https://dnf-plugins-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/post-transaction-actions.html) (as we say in pacman).

```
linux-firmware:any:rm /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-[^22].ucode.xz
```

Kindly check the command in test environment before writing the real path because I do not have dnf syatem in hand. ( Like make some files like `sudo touch /tmp/iwlwifi-7265D-{20..30}.ucode.xz` and change `/lib/firmware` to `/tmp` and update/reinstall the package and see if all execpt the 22 version is deleted)